# How to retrieve longitude and latitude from onConnected() method with Google API

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to read the latitude and the longitude from the device's current location and use these data to retrieve information from `maps.googleapis.com`.
I'm correctly able to find the user location, but when I'm not able to use the latitude and longitude values outside the onConnected() method.

I decleared the url string at the top of the `ListLoc` class.

When I try to read `url` from GetContacts() class:

`public String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+latitude+","+longitude+"&radius=1500&type=restaurant&key=my_key";`

latitude and longitude are always NULL.

Please, can you give me some suggestions on how to solve my problem?
I tried to use global variables, but I didn't solve the issue.

This is my whole code:

```
import ...


public class ListLoc extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {


    public Double latitude=0.0, longitude =0.0;
    private TextView mLatitudeTextView;
    private TextView mLongitudeTextView;
    private TextView mTextView, mTextView2;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLocation;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;


    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener listener;
    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2 * 1000;  /* 10 secs */
    private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 2000; /* 2 sec */

    private LocationManager locationManager;


    private String TAG = ListLoc.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;


    // URL to get contacts JSON
    public String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+latitude+","+longitude+"&radius=1500&type=restaurant&key=my_key";


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;


    // this functions are specified in the list_item.xml layout file
    public void onClick_name(View v) {
        TextView testo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        testo.setText("text");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_loc);

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetContacts().execute();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mLocationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        checkLocation(); //check whether location service is enable or not in your  phone



    }

        @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        startLocationUpdates();

        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if(mLocation == null){
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (mLocation != null) {

           latitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
           longitude = mLocation.getLongitude();

            // mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mLocation.getLatitude()));
            //mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mLocation.getLongitude()));


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Error: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        // Create the location request
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        // Request location updates
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d("reque", "--->>>>");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        String msg = "Updated Location: " +
                Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // You can now create a LatLng Object for use with maps
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());


        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.


    }

    private boolean checkLocation() {
        if(!isLocationEnabled())
            showAlert();
        return isLocationEnabled();
    }

    private void showAlert() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Enable Location")
                .setMessage("Your Locations Settings is set to 'Off'.\nPlease Enable Location to " +
                        "use this app")
                .setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                    }
                });
        dialog.show();
    }

    private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }


    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        ListLoc prova = new ListLoc();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListLoc.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(prova.url);


            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String icon = c.getString("icon");
                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String name = c.getString("name");



                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        // contact.put("id", id);
                        contact.put("name", name);
                        // contact.put("email", icon);


                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    ListLoc.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name"}, new int[]{R.id.name});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring `String url` at the top, `location` and `latitude` are 0.0 and the url is already set using those values.
Move the `String url` declaration into your `doInBackground` method for this to work.